Combine the values from all url parameters
Say I have a url that looks like this:
mysite.com/?filter_club_officer=President&filter_club=Houston%20Club

How can I use javascript to get this result?
President-Houston%20Club

I managed to get this far, but I don't know how to get it in the final format:


const searchParams = new URLSearchParams('filter_club_officer=President&filter_club=Houston%20Club');

for (const param of searchParams) {
  param[1];
}




Your code isn't combining anything. It's not doing anything with param[1], not even printing it.

Are you just asking how to concatenate strings in JavaScript?

Convert the values to an array and use join('-').

So in the for loop param[1] now refers to the value in each query param key-value pair (i.e., the right side the the equals sign). You now need to store the values in a string, using a "dash" sign as a delimiter.


const searchParams = new URLSearchParams('filter_club_officer=President&filter_club=Houston%20Club');
// this will store the final output variable
let output = '';
for (const param of searchParams) {
  // add the query param value to output
  output += param[1] + "-";
}
// now, output is 'President-Houston Club-'
// so we wanna remove the final dash:

output = output.slice(0, -1);
console.log(output);




Thank you! Still learning JS the hard way, and this helped me understand what I need to do.
